# Being a cam girl from home and moving to the U.K

Tags: usa, united-kingdom

I am 24 yrs old and single. I am self employed and work from home as a webcam model for an online website. I want to move to London, England. What all do I need to do to move from the U.S. to the UK? And would I be able to continue being self employed as a cam girl?

Comment: What is your citizenship? Self-employed work-online workers are still a big grey area for many countries visa-wise.

Comment: I don't think this will be permissible unless you have some kind of visa specifically for setting up your own business.

Answer (score 1):

The UK visa system no longer has the Tier 1 visa which permits someone to enter the UK and be self-employed. Tier 1 Entrepreneur is to attract people to invest in the United Kingdom by setting up or taking over, and being actively involved in the running of, one or more businesses. Tier 1 Entrepreneur visa are ideal for entrepreneurs with some money to invest in the UK. In practice most people who apply will need to have £200,000 of available funds held in a regulated financial institution.

The Tier 1 Entrepreneur sub-category is perfect for those individuals wishing to start a business in the UK who can meet the criteria. Tier 1 (Entrepreneur) is for non-European migrants who want to invest in the UK by setting up or taking over, and being actively involved in the running of a business.

A 'business' means an enterprise as:

a sole trader

a partnership, or

a company registered in the UK

For your application for a Tier 1 Entrepreneur visa to be successful you must score a total of 95 points and meet all the other requirements under the Immigration Rules.